# Requesting high precision location with LocationSettingsRequest not updating location settings

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I'm using the new `LocationSettingsRequest` system to request high accuracy locations. If my device is set to power saving mode for example, would prompt a system dialog to update the location accuracy. This works in most cases but in some devices the following happens:

1. If the device is set to power saving mode, the system dialog asks for gps permission and changes to gps only if confirmed.
2. If the device is set to gps only, the system asks for wifi and google services to improve location and changes to power saving mode location if confirmed.

Here is how I set the `LocationSettingsRequest`:

```
val builder = LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
    .addLocationRequest(createLocationRequest(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY))
    .addLocationRequest(createLocationRequest(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY))
    .setAlwaysShow(true)

settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(builder.build())
```

This triggers the Google Play Services system dialog to update the location accuracy settings. But for example on a Samsung Galaxy S6 running Android 7.0, the location is never updated to high accuracy.

The same happens when I try the Google Location example available [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location). In the `locationupdates` folder, check the `startLocationUpdates()` method where the settings resolution is called:

```
private void startLocationUpdates() {
    // Begin by checking if the device has the necessary location settings.
    mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "All location settings are satisfied.");

                    //noinspection MissingPermission
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                            mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());

                    updateUI();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                    switch (statusCode) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            Log.i(TAG, "Location settings are not satisfied. Attempting to upgrade " +
                                    "location settings ");
                            try {
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(), and check the
                                // result in onActivityResult().
                                ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                Log.i(TAG, "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            String errorMessage = "Location settings are inadequate, and cannot be " +
                                    "fixed here. Fix in Settings.";
                            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;
                    }

                    updateUI();
                }
            });
}
```

Running this sample app on this Samsung device causes the same problem. The `onActivityResult()` is called for the `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` case.

Has anyone been through something similar? Any ideas on how to address the problem?

Comment: Checked the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#location-request), it was defined that `PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY` uses WiFi and cell tower positioning and `PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY` is more likely to use GPS. If you read further [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest#setPriority(int)), it was also defined. You can also get an idea from the performance hint written in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings.html#get-settings).

Comment: Thanks. I'm doing exactly what the doc says. Also tried different combinations of `LocationRequest` objects added to the `LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()`. In most devices it works and I get the location settings updated to high accuracy. Only in one test device I have, the location settings switch from battery to gps only and back. Never to high accuracy.

Comment: Note that if I disable location completely, then the code above actually works. It enables location and switch it to high accuracy. Only when location is already enabled but in battery-saving or gps-only modes that it fails to switch to high accuracy.

Comment: looks like it's a bug introduced in last google play services update...I am facing exactly the same issue in some devices like Mi Redmi, Gionee...Did you find any workaround?

Comment: Unfortunately the only thing I did for now was to redirect the user to the location settings when that happens. :(

Comment: This issue is reproducible on emulator, I filed a bug report: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138190015

Answer (score 1):

Having the same issue in android 8.0 and 8.1 devices. I solved the issue by changing the location mode to Battery Saving.

```
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
```

Replaced the HIGH_ACCURACY request.